# Viewing Queue contents using the Azure Dashboard

Tags: azure, queue

Using the Azure dashboard, how do you view the contents (current messages) of a Queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Azure dashboard", do you refer to Azure Portal "https://portal.azure.com" ?

portal is more for manage your cloud resource but not the actual content. you will need to look for other third party tooling.

Storage Explorer would be a good one to look at: http://storageexplorer.com/
and Azure Storage Explorer http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/

Comment: Yes, I meant the Azure Portal.  Thanks for the third party tool suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can do this in Azure dashboard:

> **How to view the contents (current messages) of a Queue from the Azure Dashboard**

1. Login to **Azure portal**
2. Find the **Storage Account** associated to the queue.
3. Navigate to **Queues**.
4. Find the named queue and click it.
5. From the Overview you will see a load of rows with columns including **"insertion times"** and **"expiration times"** as well as **"Message Text"**.
6. Click a **row** to see it's contents: [Here is an example of what this looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwg0j.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have (2) good options - [**VS IDE Cloud Explorer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-resources-managing-with-cloud-explorer) OR
Microsoft has [**Azure Storage Explorer**](http://storageexplorer.com/) now which is based on Electron. This project was [formerly known as Deco](https://github.com/Azure/deco/releases).

[CodePlex is shutting down December 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/03/31/shutting-down-codeplex/) - Azure Storage Explorer will no longer exist!